# Creating pdf from Blob Field

Tags: vb.net, pdf, blob, pdfmake

I know this question has been asked quite a number of times before, but mine is slightly different. I have managed to create the pdf from blob field, but when opening the pdf, Adobe gives an error "There was an error opening this document. This file is damaged and could not be repaired." Is it that I am going wrong somewhere when creating the pdf. I would appreciate any help in this matter as I have been struggling with it for the past few days, without getting much help. My code to create the pdf is as below.

```
Dim rs As MySqlDataReader
    Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rawData() As Byte
    Dim FileSize As UInt32
    Dim fs As FileStream

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    sqlstr = "Select pdf_file,pdf_file_size from pdf_files where id=" & TextBox1.Text
    cmd.Connection = mySqlConn
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstr

    rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While rs.Read()
        FileSize = rs.GetUInt32(rs.GetOrdinal("vat_file_size"))
        rawData = New Byte(FileSize) {}

        rs.GetBytes(rs.GetOrdinal("vat_file"), 0, rawData, 0, FileSize)
        'rs.GetBytes(rs.Item(0), 0, rawData, 0, FileSize)

        fs = New FileStream("C:\Users\name\Desktop\test.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)

        fs.Write(rawData, 0, FileSize + 1)
        fs.Flush()
        fs.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("File successfully written to disk!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    End While
    rs.Close()
```

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake while copying your code here. The Columns' names don't match (maybe you can just get `rs("pdf_file")`. Also, it looks like you're asking for a single record, so the loop is not exactly required). Then, see that `FileSize` actually matches the `rawData` length: read the Column value directly to a byte array and compare. Of course, assuming that the PDF bytes were stored correctly.

Comment: Hi, I have corrected the mismatch columns. and have noticed that the raw data length is less then FileSize by 1. Could that be the reason